# Excel add-in insert a template worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm building an Excel Add in on the ribbon for Excel 2016. I currently have a button which when clicked triggers a Macro which should insert a template into the workbook.

So far I have tried to achieve this by hiding a worksheet in the add-in and then trying to toggle it's visibility by pressing the button:

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Insert the R2A sheet into the Excel file
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Sub insertSheet()

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("R2A").Visible = 1
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("R2A").Select

End Sub
```

Unfortunately it's not working and I receive a `runtime error 9 subscript out of range`. Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're an add-in: you live at the *application* level. `ThisWorkbook` is you, `ActiveWorkbook` is whichever workbook is active, **if any**.

Your code assumes there's an active workbook, and will blow up with a runtime error 91 if it runs when `ActiveWorkbook` is `Nothing`.

But that's not the problem you're asking about.

*Subscript out of range* in this context, means that `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("R2A")` doesn't exist. If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, the sheet named "R2A" would be in `ThisWorkbook` (the add-in's "hidden" workbook), not in the active workbook.

That sheet has a specific meaning in your add-in. Give it a *code name* (i.e. in the *properties* pane (F4), set its `(name)` property), and then refer to it by that. For example call it `TemplateSheet`, and then just copy it:

```
If ActiveWorkbook Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
TemplateSheet.Copy ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Dim templateCopy As Worksheet
Set templateCopy = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
```

Then work with `templateCopy` and `ActiveWorkbook` to rename and move the copied sheet as/if needed.

You don't need to hide the template sheet (and then un-hide its copy), since `ThisWorkbook` (the add-in's workbook) doesn't exist as a *workbook* in Excel (it's an add-in!).

Answer (score 0):

Creating the sheet and having it hidden in the background is restrictive, considering the code to dynamically add a sheet is very simple:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub insertSheet()

    Dim i As Integer
    i = Sheets.Count

    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(i + 1).Select

End Sub
```

This will add a sheet at the end of the last sheet and then select it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `True` is not 1 but -1 in VBA. Try this in the `immediate` window of the VBE:

```
CDbl(true)
```

If I am correct then you might want to change

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("R2A").Visible = 1
```

to

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("R2A").Visible = True
```

Also, you might want to try

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("R2A").Activate
```

Comment: Actually `CBool(1)` returns `True`. The only thing that's set in stone is that 0 is `False` - any other integer value converts to `True`. `CInt(True)` (or `CDbl(True)` for that matter) returns -1 because, well, VBA needed to map a non-zero value to `True`. But any non-zero value will convert to a Boolean `True` also.

Comment: Interesting to know. Normally, I would now delete my above post. But since I believe your comment to be rather informative I feel reluctant to do so. Thanks for the insight.